# Can ElasticSearch aggregate over top N items in each sorted bucket

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this query that buckets the records by data source code, and computes an average over all records in each bucket.

How could I modify it so that each bucket is limited to having (at most) top N records when ordered by record.timestamp desc (or any other record field for that matter)

The end effect I want is an average per bucket using the most recent N records rather than all records (so the doc_count in each bucket would have an upper limit of N).

I've searched and experimented extensively with no success.

Current query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "jobType": "LiveEventScoring"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "host": "MTVMDANS"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "measurement": "EventDataLoadFromCacheDuration"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "data-sources": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "dataSourceCode"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "avgDuration": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "elapsedMs"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Results in:

```
"aggregations": {
    "data-sources": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "AU_VIRT",
          "doc_count": 6259,
          "avgDuration": {
            "value": 3525.683176226234
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "AU_HN_VIRT",
          "doc_count": 2812,
          "avgDuration": {
            "value": 3032.0771692745375
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "GB_VIRT",
          "doc_count": 1845,
          "avgDuration": {
            "value": 1432.39945799458
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Alternately if grabbing top N from sorted bucket is not possible, I could do multiple queries one for each dataSourceCode, e.g. for AU_VIRT:

```
{
  "size":0,
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "jobType": "LiveEventScoring"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "host": "MTVMDANS"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "dataSourceCode": "AU_VIRT"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "measurement": "EventDataLoadFromCacheDuration"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
      "aggs": {
        "avgDuration": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "elapsedMs"
          }
        }
      }

  }
}
```

but I am now challenged in how I make the avgDuration work on top N results sorted by timestamp desc.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, you'd need to queries to do this or maybe use Watcher to run one aggregation, index the results in another index and then run the final aggregation on this second index.

Comment: Okay thanks Andrei - that's what I suspected but I wanted to make sure I was not missing something.

Comment: @AndreiStefan - I'm now trying again by ditching the terms aggregation that buckets, and instead just run one separate query per dataSourceCode. I am finding that the top N on a sorted query to be elusive in E.S.